# Take a scaled or proportional amount of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a built-in method to do something like `Take[list,Scaled[.7]]`?

Comment: `ArrayResample[list, Scaled[0.7]] `

Comment: I got excited for a minute. But this doesn't do what I want to do, namely, take the first say 70% of a list.

Comment: In that case, you should just use `Take[list, Round[0.7*Length@list]]` or `Take[list, Floor[0.7*Length@list]]`.

Comment: Right, that’s what my code below does. Was just thinking a Scaled option to the Take functions (or alternative specification) would be better.

Comment: Better in what way?  It is certainly not better to overriding a builtin.  You could always `scaledTake[lst_List, p_Real /; 0 < p < 1] := 
 Take[lst, Floor[p*Length[lst]]]`.

Comment: Right. I think you mean it’s better to not override a built in. I agree.

Comment: Better in terms of convenience and intuitiveness etc. A convenience function the same way TakeDrop is.

Answer (score -1):

One approach is this:

```
Unprotect[Take]
Take[l_, Scaled[p_]] := Take[l, Ceiling[p Length@l]]
Take[l_, UpTo[Scaled[p_]]] := Take[l, Floor[p Length@l]]
Protect[Take]
```

which works. The idea is the regular Scaled call goes at least that high, but the UpTo@Scaled call goes no more than that high.

It works for negative numbers too but I'm not sure it's correct (might need to switch ceiling and floor in that case). And it'd have to be extended for ranges of scaled's. But seems like this should be built-in maybe? Or is there an easier way of doing it?

It's probably most useful in the `TakeDrop` context actually.